# ng2-smart-table not rer-endering after source change

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

This may look very common. But I am facing this problem for few days.

I am using ng2-smart-table, which is being updated with data from rest API. The data is being loaded for the first time after asynchronous call.

However, after an event in a different component, after emitting, I can see that the same method is called, data is being fetched for the same table, but table is not re-rendered with new data this time.Can anyone help on this?

The code snippet I am using as below for the data table reload.

```
private getQuestions()
  {
    this._questionService.getAll().subscribe(data => 

      {
      //this.data = data;
      //this.source.load(slice();
      this.data.load(data);
      this.data.reset();
      //this.data.update()
      this.data.refresh();
      console.log('Data length:'+this.data.count());
      this.cd.markForCheck();
      },
      error=> console.log("Error: "+error));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the source every time the data gets loaded. Most likely it is getting appended.